# When i press enter in text pane Document Listener call first instead key listener

Tags: java, keylistener, jtextpane, documentlistener

Iam doing some example on event listener in java. I add two listener on `JTextPane` key Listener and Document Listener. When I insert into the text pane always `KeyListener` call first then `DocumentListener` but when press "enter" key  it call `DocumentListener` and then call `KeyListener`.

Actually I am not understand why this happen when I only press "Enter" key?

Comment: Generally spoken you should not rely on the order of the events.

Comment: But the order must be keyListener then DocumentListener  why it happen only in case of "Enter" key